# Get The next days but not weekends, asp.net c#

Tags: c#, .net, date

Im trying to get the next five weekdays and im stuck.

Ive started like this:

```
        List<DateTime> allWeekEndsInOneYear = new List<DateTime>();

        DateTime sDate = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime eDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);

        TimeSpan diff = eDate - sDate;
        int days = diff.Days;
        for (var i = 0; i <= days; i++)
        {
            var testDate = sDate.AddDays(i);
            switch (testDate.DayOfWeek)
            {
                case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
                    allWeekEndsInOneYear.Add(testDate);
                    break;
            }
        }

        List<DateTime> daysToMark = new List<DateTime>();

        DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);
```

Now I need to fill daysToMark with the next 5 days excluding the weekeds (the ones in allWeekEndsInOneYear). Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Do you want all workdays in a year, or only the next five workdays?

Comment: `Saturday` and `Sunday` are not weekend in every locale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the next five days that are not a Saturday or Sunday.

```
var nextFiveWeekDays = new List<DateTime>();
var testDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

while (nextFiveWeekDays.Count()<5)
{
  if (testDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && 
           testDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
     nextFiveWeekDays.Add(testDate);

testDate = testDate.AddDays(1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add other days (which are not weekends) on default case of switch:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= days; i++)
{
    var testDate = sDate.AddDays(i);
    switch (testDate.DayOfWeek)
    {
        case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
        case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
            allWeekEndsInOneYear.Add(testDate);
            break;
        default:
            daysToMark.Add(testDate); // this is a workday
            break;
    } 
}
```

Also you don't need to calculate days count and use `for` loop. `while(testDate <= eDate)` will do the job:

```
var testDate = DateTime.Now;

while (testDate <= eDate)
{
    switch (testDate.DayOfWeek)
    {
       case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
       case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
            allWeekEndsInOneYear.Add(testDate);
            break;
       default:
            daysToMark.Add(testDate); // this is a workday
            break;
    }

    testDate = testDate.AddDays(1);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it right, but a think he asked only for the next five workdays. You're giving him a whole year. I'm also not sure why he enumerated all weekend days in a year...

Comment: @LMB yes, he also said to exclude weekends in first list (which are for whole year), so I decided that workdays also needed for whole year